# contraction product of two tensors

Tags: tensor-products

Let $\mathbf{F}$ be a tensor that is formed with vectors $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ of the type ($T$ stands for the transpose of the matrix)

$\mathbf{F} = \mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{b} + (\mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{b})^T$

I need to find the tensor contraction of $\mathbf{F}$ with $\mathbf{c} \otimes \mathbf{c}$

$$\mathbf{F}: \mathbf{c} \otimes \mathbf{c} =  [\mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{b} + (\mathbf{a} \otimes \mathbf{b})^T ]: \mathbf{c} \otimes \mathbf{c} \\
= (\mathbf{a} \cdot\mathbf{c})(\mathbf{b} \cdot\mathbf{c}) + (\mathbf{a} \cdot\mathbf{c})(\mathbf{b} \cdot\mathbf{c})\\
= 2(\mathbf{a} \cdot\mathbf{c})(\mathbf{b} \cdot\mathbf{c})
 $$

Is this simplification correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is.
Check with Einsten notation

$$F_{ij} = a_ib_j+a_jb_i$$
then
$$F_{ij}c_{i}c_{j} = a_ib_jc_{i}c_{j}+a_jb_ic_{i}c_{j} = 2a_ic_{i}b_jc_{j}$$